# angularJs $resource post to c# controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I trying post data to the c# controller, but it doesn't come within.
orderId is an int and orders is an array

```
return $resource(myConfig.backend + '/orders/index/:A?orders=:B', { A: orderID, B: orderArray });
```

c# controller:

```
[ActionName("index")]
public void index(int id, string orders)
{

}
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working know.

I fix it with $http

Comment: The only one that can mark this as correct is you. You may have to wait awhile since you answered it yourself..Great!!!!!!!!!